# Obtaining user app_metadata in my resource server using OIDC and Oauth v2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0, openid-connect

I'm struggling to clearly understand the flow of obtaining user `app_metadata` after an authenticated user sends a request to my `Resource Server` with an `Access Token`.

I've seen [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47636823/which-information-gets-sent-in-each-api-request-using-oidc) on Stack Overflow, but they didn't clarify things enough.

For example, the information I need to obtain is users `organizationId` (`234`) and `organizationRole` (`POWER_USER`).

Can this information be loaded on the `Access-Token`? If not, does this mean that my `Resource Server` has to call the authorization server (`Auth0`) each time to check these parameters? B/C I see that the `ID` token isn't being sent with the request.

Is this the best practice? Doesn't this bring a latency toll to call `Authorization Server` to check these details on each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this (while limiting the amount of requests needed) is to add the data to the token via a [custom claim](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims#custom-claims). This can be done in a Rule if you are using auth0, and there is an example on the doc I linked.